# How to avoid camera output shown multiple times in android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming

I am trying to develop an android application with the laptop as host and phone as client.I am using network HUD.When I run the code in unity it displays as expected.But output is displayed multiple times and appears as noise in android phone?Please let me know if there is a solution.[image]